# Is there a way with Angular that I can check if a password and confirm password are the same?

Tags: angularjs

I started to use some of the model options with Angular such as ng-minlength="3" and ng-required. These work well and set the error field when the input is not correct.

Is there a way that I can use these options to also help me check that a password and a confirm password are the same or do I need to add some javascript for this?  I am not sure it makes a difference but this will all be checks in modern browsers IE10 and above.

Comment: I've used this a couple time, http://scotch.io/demos/angular-validation let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can resuse [this directive](https://github.com/TheSharpieOne/angular-input-match) to match any two fields

```
Password: <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" />
Confirm: <input ng-model="user.passwordConfirm" type="password" data-match="user.password" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom directive to validate the input:

```
var app = angular.module('sample', [])
    .directive('equalsTo', [function () {
    /*
     * <input type="password" ng-model="Password" />
     * <input type="password" ng-model="ConfirmPassword" equals-to="Password" />
     */
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // Use only as attribute
        scope: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, control) {
            var check = function () {
                var v1 = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel); // attrs.ngModel = "ConfirmPassword"                   
                var v2 = scope.$eval(attrs.equalsTo).$viewValue; // attrs.equalsTo = "Password"
                return v1 == v2;
            };
            scope.$watch(check, function (isValid) {
                control.$setValidity("equalsTo", isValid);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here's a sample

```
<input name="Password" required ng-minlength="6" />
<input name="ConfirmPassword" required equals-to="registerForm.Password" />
```

Full sample: http://jsfiddle.net/meziantou/bA6vm/light/